# Changing ID attributes to Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

I'm a JS beginner, and I made a JS code for a dropdown menu, it is working very good, but because of a wordpress configuration I need to change my code. Now it's not ID's attributes but Class, the names are still the same, but I just want to change ID to class.

Here is my small JS code :

```
var linkId = "dropdown-" + $(this).attr("id");
                if ($('.dropdown-sub').is(':animated')){
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    $('.dropdown-sub').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).attr("id") !== linkId) {
                            if($(this).hasClass('open-dd')) {

                                $(this).slideUp();
                            }
                            $(this).removeClass('open-dd');
                        } else {
                            if($('#' + linkId).hasClass('open-dd')) {

                                $('#' + linkId).slideUp();
                                $('#' + linkId).removeClass('open-dd');
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#' + linkId).slideDown();
                                $('#' + linkId).addClass('open-dd');
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu-link" class="menu-link cacher-menu">
            <ul class="optionel">
                <li  class="first primary-nav first">
                    <a><span class="menu-text">Un groupe individuel en évolution</span></a>
                    <span class="font-awesome f1"></span>
            <div class="dropdown-sub dropdown-first">
                <div class="dd-e">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">200 ans d'histoire</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Une multitude d'activités</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Une mosaïque de sociétés</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Une présence internationale</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="last">Des femmes et des hommes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
```

If you want more informations about this problem ask me directly. Thank you.  Andrew Bernard

Comment: Is this your new HTML or old one? I don't see any IDs except menu-link @bernard

Comment: This is the new one, (wordpress one), with class first and dropdown-first instead of ID

Comment: I think you can try by using hasClass() method

Comment: Ok, what I need to replace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code,

Only the list `li` has changed the ID `first` to class `first`.

So in that case,

```
 <li  class="first primary-nav first">


var linkId = "dropdown-" + $(this).attr("class").split(" ").pop();
```

This will return you the `first` class. but it's based on assumption that `first` will always be at the end.

If it will be at beginning then,

```
var linkId = "dropdown-" + $(this).attr("class").split(" ").shift();
```

`shift` will return you class at the beginning.

Now inside your

```
 $('.dropdown-sub').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).attr("id") !== linkId) {
```

To check whether class `dropdown-first` is available:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass(linkId)) {
```

This will check if `dropdown-first` is available or not.

> So your entire code will be come:

```
$(function () {
$("nav li").click(function () {
    var linkId = "dropdown-" + $(this).attr("class").split(" ").pop();
    if ($('.dropdown-sub').is(':animated')) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        $('.dropdown-sub').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass(linkId)) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('open-dd')) {

                    $(this).slideUp();
                }
                                              $(this).removeClass('open-dd');

            } else {
                if ($('.' + linkId).hasClass('open-dd')) {

                    $('.' + linkId).slideUp();
                    $('.' + linkId).removeClass('open-dd');
                } else {
                    $('.' + linkId).slideDown();
                    $('.' + linkId).addClass('open-dd');
                }
            }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4z44gzs0/1/)**

Comment: Thank you mohamedrias, for your explanations which are very good, step by step. But I try it, it doesn't work, strange.

Comment: Oh, could you please setup a jsfiddle.net with all menu related code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/broy/gtm5ewLv/ Here it is, i'm not sure if there's the entire CSS

Comment: Ok the CSS is complete now

Comment: Great, what have you changed ? Only JS ?

Comment: There was one change in HTML, even the second .dropdown-sub was having dropdown-first class. Then the JS was not proper and no click event was there before

Comment: Just a last thing, I have this code just before this your new JS code, how i can  adjust them together ?

    $(function() {

    $("nav li.primary-nav").click(function() {
     var linkA = $(this).children('a');
     
     if (linkA.hasClass('activation')) {
      $("nav li.primary-nav a").removeClass('activation')
      linkA.removeClass('activation');
     }
     else {
      $("nav li.primary-nav a").removeClass('activation')
      linkA.addClass('activation');
     }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74712/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-bernard).

Comment: Perhaps I don't need this first part JS anymore with your code now ?

Answer (score 0):

an id selector in jQuery looks like this (how you already figured out):

```
$("#my_id_name")
```

a class selector in jQuery looks like this:

```
$(".my_class_name")
```

so you just need to prepend a `.` instead of a `#` to select classes.
just change this in your code and you should be fine